# Создание sql таблицы на magento

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

Мне надо создать таблицу в базе данных, но у меня не получается. Вот код :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <config>
     <modules>
         <DS_News>
             <version>0.0.1</version>
         </DS_News>
     </modules>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <dsnews>
                <file>ds_news.xml</file>
            </dsnews>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <routers>
        <dsnews>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>DS_News</module>
                <frontName>news</frontName>
            </args>
        </dsnews>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<global>
    <models>
        <dsnews>
            <resourceModel>dsnews_resource</resourceModel>
        </dsnews>
        <dsnews_resource>
            <entities>
                <table_news>
                    <table>ds_news_entities</table>
                </table_news>
            </entities>
        </dsnews_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <dsnews_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>DS_News</module>
            </setup>
        </dsnews_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
```

у меня файл **install-0.0.1.php**.

```
 <?php
       $installer = $this;
       $tableNews = $installer->getTable('dsnews/table_news');
       $installer->startSetup();
       $connection = $installer->getConnection();
       $installer->getConnection()->dropTable($tableNews);
       $table = $installer->getConnection()
        ->newTable($tableNews)
        ->addColumn('news_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
            'identity'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'primary'   => true,
            ))
        ->addColumn('title', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, '255', array(
            'nullable'  => false,
            ))
        ->addColumn('content', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
            'nullable'  => false,
            ))
        ->addColumn('created', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME, null, array(
            'nullable'  => false,
        ));
       $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
       $installer->endSetup();
?>
```

В таблице **core_resource**  я получаю строку с атрибутом `dsnews_setup`, но  таблицу не получаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что вы получили в таблице core_resource строку с атрибутом, означает, что скрипт инсталяции отработал без ошибок, а это вероятнее всего значит, что неверно составлен config.xml модуля. Предполагаю, что magento не хватает определения и наличия class`ов DS_News_Model, DS_News_Model_Resource и DS_News_Model_Resource_Setup, которые сообщат инсталятору как совершает обращения к базе ваш модуль

```
<global>
    <models>
        <dsnews>
            <class>DS_News_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>dsnews_resource</resourceModel>
        </dsnews>
        <dsnews_resource>
            <class>DS_News_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <table_news>
                    <table>ds_news_entities</table>
                </table_news>
            </entities>
        </dsnews_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```

Из всей информации по magento, обнаруженой мной в сети, могу порекомендовать [этот ресурс](https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Create+a+custom+module+with+a+custom+database+table). И, конечно, читать исходники. Удачи с magento!